# inequality using propagation function $w$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Supose that $w \in W^{1,1}((0,\infty)\times (0,\infty))$ (Sobolev space) need satisfy the conditions of proposition 4.9 of Prüss (evolutionari integral equations 2012, pg. 109)., $t, \ \kappa >0$, $0<\eta<1$. Can we conclude that exist $C>0$ such that

$$\int_0^{\frac{t}{\kappa}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} w(t;\tau) t^\eta \tau^{-\eta}d\tau \leq C, \ \forall t>0?$$

Comment: No, since there are certainly functions $w$ in this space for which the integral does not converge for any $t \in (0,1)$. Take e.g. $w$ such that $w_\tau(t;\tau) =  \frac{1}{\tau |\log \tau|^2}$ for $ 0 < t, \, \tau \le 1$, suitably extended to all positive $t, \, \tau$.

Comment: @HansEngler $w$ need satisfy the conditions of proposition 4.9 of Prüss (evolutionari integral equations 2012, pg. 109).

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva: That seems like information that should be spelled out in the question. Not everybody will have access to the book.

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva You are assuming that $w$ is the propagation function of a completely monotonic measure. I don't think that this assumption is sufficient to reach your desired conclusions.   *Jan Prüss, who was a very thorough mathematician, would have stated this somewhere if it were possible.*